# case life cycle on pega designer studio

Tags: lifecycle, pega

I am beginner on pega developer, right now i take a lesson from pega academy and i take "System Architect Essential" and topic about case life cycle.

In designer studio i can't find + add step in life cycle tab. Where is step of life cycle on pega designer studio.

[image]

I only find add stages, and contain of +add stages is different with +add step which is there is no utilities on +add stages.

[image]

[image]

Sorry if the title is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are on Add Stage step.
Give the name for your stage and click outside of the input field.

After that there will be an option(+ icon) to add a Step under that Stage.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a process to a stage
Add a process when there are relevant actions users can take on a case while it is your stage. You can specify the conditions under which the process is visible to the user.

1. In Case Designer, click a stage name.
2. Click User actions.
3. Click + Add process and select the name of a flow in the first field that is displayed.

Alternatively, you can enter a name and click the magnifying glass icon to create a new flow.

4. Optional: Press the Down Arrow key in the Allowed when field and select the name of a when condition.
5. Alternatively, you can enter a name and click the magnifying glass icon to create a new when condition.

Click Save.

Reference: https://community1.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v719/procomhelpmain.htm#tools/casedesigner/stages/actions/tsk_addprocess.htm

Comment: You have simply copied the information provided under that link. Please note that linking to a source after copying their content word-for-word is still a copyright infringement. The [terms](https://www.pega.com/terms) of the website clearly do not allow you to do this. You have to write your own answer in your own words, and you can back it up with a source like this, but you cannot simply copy other people's work and paste it here without acquiring proper licensing rights first.